# Why do we need countability of A to prove proposition 1.3 in Folland Real Analysis?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

**1.3 Proposition** *If A is countable, then $\oplus_{\alpha\in A}\mathcal{M}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\{\prod_{\alpha\in A}E_\alpha:E_\alpha\in\mathcal{M}_\alpha \}$*

I understand the proof, but where did the proof make use of countability of A? Is it because if A is not countable, then 
$\prod_{\alpha\in A}E_\alpha=\bigcap_{\alpha\in A}\pi^{-1}(E_\alpha)$ is not necessarily true since $\sigma$-algebra is only closed under countable intersections?

Proof here:
If $E_\alpha\in\mathcal{M}_\alpha$,then $\pi^{-1}(E_\alpha)=\prod_{\beta\in A}E_\beta$ where $E_\beta=X_\beta$ for $\beta\neq\alpha$; on the other hand, $\prod_{\alpha\in A}E_\alpha=\bigcap_{\alpha\in A}\pi^{-1}(E_\alpha)$. The result therefore follows from Lemma 1.1.

**Lemma 1.1** *If $\mathcal{E}\subset\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{F})$ then $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{E})\subset\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{F})$.*

Comment: "but where did the proof make use of countability of A?" I don't know because I don't have the book...

Answer (score 2):

By definition, $\otimes_{\alpha \in A}\mathcal{M}_\alpha = \mathcal{M}(\{\pi^{-1}_\alpha(E_\alpha): E_\alpha \in \mathcal{M}_\alpha, \alpha \in A \}) $ (the $\sigma$-algebra generated by..).
If $A$ is countable, we have to show that this is equal to $\mathcal{M}(\{ \Pi_{\alpha \in A} E_\alpha: E_\alpha \in \mathcal{M}_\alpha \})$.
$$
\pi^{-1}_\alpha(E_\alpha)=\Pi_{\beta \in A}E_\beta, E_\beta = X_\beta \text{ if } \beta \ne \alpha \\
\implies \pi^{-1}_\alpha(E_\alpha) \subset \mathcal{M}(\{ \Pi_{\alpha \in A} E_\alpha: E_\alpha \in \mathcal{M}_\alpha \}) \\
\implies \mathcal{M}(\{\pi^{-1}_\alpha(E_\alpha): E_\alpha \in \mathcal{M}_\alpha, \alpha \in A \}) \subset \mathcal{M}(\{ \Pi_{\alpha \in A} E_\alpha: E_\alpha \in \mathcal{M}_\alpha \}) \\
\implies \otimes_{\alpha \in A}\mathcal{M}_\alpha \subset \mathcal{M}(\{ \Pi_{\alpha \in A} E_\alpha: E_\alpha \in \mathcal{M}_\alpha \})
$$
Now we have to show the opposite inclusion. 
$$ 
\Pi_{\alpha \in A} E_\alpha = \bigcap_{\alpha \in A}\pi^{-1}_\alpha(E_\alpha)
$$
Now, since each $\pi^{-1}_\alpha(E_\alpha) \in \otimes_{\alpha \in A}\mathcal{M}_\alpha $ and $\sigma$-algebras are closed under COUNTABLE intersections, we have that $\Pi_{\alpha \in A} E_\alpha \in \otimes_{\alpha \in A}\mathcal{M}_\alpha $. Therefore: 
$$
\{ \Pi_{\alpha \in A} E_\alpha: E_\alpha \in \mathcal{M}_\alpha \} \subset \otimes_{\alpha \in A}\mathcal{M}_\alpha  \\
\implies \mathcal{M}(\{ \Pi_{\alpha \in A} E_\alpha: E_\alpha \in \mathcal{M}_\alpha \}) \subset \otimes_{\alpha \in A}\mathcal{M}_\alpha
$$

Comment: Each $f$ in $\pi^{-1}(E_{\alpha})$ is only restricted to have $f(\alpha)\in E_{\alpha}$ so it seems like it is a much larger group of functions than $\{\prod_{\alpha \in A} E_{\alpha}:E_{\alpha}\in M_{\alpha} \}$ which restricts the value of $f$ for EVERY $\alpha$ in $A$. For that reason I'm finding it hard to see how the second line of the begin{align} holds.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose that $A$ is not countable. So, a $\sigma$-algebra $M$ is $\oplus_{a \in A} M_a$. We could choose a subfamily $B$ of $A$ which is uncountable. Then, $\bigcap_{b \in B} \oplus_{a\in A} M_a = \oplus_{b \in B} M_b$ exists. So, infinite intersections always exist, for every set $B$ smaller than $A$! Contradiction.

Comment: what do you mean by the left side of the equation? b is not used...

Comment: I mean that in all cases, infinite intersection would have to exist. Look at the proof once again.